# Why would re-referencing ebp register segfaul when esp doesn't?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is there a reason why de-referencing the `ebp` register would segfault a program when
de-referencing the `esp` register doesn't?
Both registers contain the same value.

For example, the below code snippet will crash for me

```
mov ebp, esp
mov eax, [ebp]
```

but the next code snippet won't

```
mov eax, [esp]
```

I've included a complete nasm program that crashes with this problem.
I'm stumped as to the reason.

```
section .text
global main

%define TEST 'My test'

BITS 32

main:
    push dword msg
    jmp print_message

carry_on_here:

    mov eax, 1   ;  The system call (sys_exit)
    int 0x80     ; System interupt which invokes the kernel 

print_message:
    mov ebp, esp ; Store esp in ebp
    mov ecx, [ebp] ; <---- CRASH BECAUSE OF THIS, works with "mov ecx, [esp]"
    mov edx, len ; Length of message

    mov ebx, 1   ; the stdout file descriptor
    mov eax,4    ; the system call (sys_write)
    int 0x80     ; system interupt which invokes the kernel

    jmp carry_on_here

section .bss
section .data ; The memory here is initialised

msg db  "My message"    ,10 ;the message. Allocate d (initialised), b (bytes) , 10 of them which is: db "Initalised" 10
len equ $ - msg         ;the message length
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

So the issue was how I was compiling and linking the program.
Initially I started with x64 assembly, then changed over to x86.
I'd missed changing the nasm `-f` option to `elf32` so it was still on `elf64`.
After making this change the `epb` register de-references without crashing.

Comment: Cannot replicate problem. Works fine for me. Assembled as "nasm -f elf32 myprog.asm", linked as "ld -o myprog myprog.o -e main -melf_i386". What did you do?

Comment: Is it giving you a specific error message?

Comment: Step through the code instructionwise in a debugger and see what's going on?

Comment: I first thought of a problem with the segment registers, but both esp and ebp use SS as default segment. Couldn't hurt checking the contents of the segment registers, though.

Comment: Thanks frank! I was building it incorrectly. Should have been "-f elf32" but I'd left elf64 in there.